# How do I empty the lists after each iteration?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Here I've allowed numbers to be entered as a string which is then converted into a list, and at the end I have set x and y to be empty lists again, but it outputs a graph using data values from each iteration so that there are 3 different lines on the graph output, instead of just one.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

xyz = int(input("How many graphs would you like to create? "))
n=1

for i in range(xyz):
    x = input("Enter a your x variables, starting from the smallest with a space between each: ")
    x=x.split() #takes the input and turns it into a list
    print(x)
    y = input("Enter a your y variables, starting from the smallest with a space between each: ")
    y=y.split()

    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.savefig("Desktop/python/graph"+str(n)+".png")
    x = []
    y = []
    n=n+1
```

Comment: You are setting `x` and `y` to  new values on each iteration. Setting them to empty lists at the end of an iteration is redundant in the code you've shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are plotting into the same figure. Clear the figure with [`plt.clf()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.clf.html).